# Is there a 5$-30$ IaaS that supports some rolling-release distro?

Tags: architecture

Is there a 5$-30$ IaaS that supports some [rolling-release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release) distro?

I consider a rolling-rlease OS (like ArchLinux) upon non rolling ones or at least upon a **rolling-combo** such as a *rolling Win10 + Vagrant + rolling-Ubuntu*) to save resources (both hardware and money).

ArchLinux seems to me to be the most communal and documented one out there but I might be wrong in that assumption.

I once asked DigitalOcean if they offer any IaaS VPSs ("droplets") with ArchLInux but a staff member told me they had that option and removed it for technical conflicts with their system and services.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a product recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linode is one of these (see [linode.com](https://linode.com)). Linode offers 5$ ArchLinux and yesterday I talked with their staff and two staff members confirmed to me that they can't find any plans to stop supporting it in the future, so that's good.

[According to ArchLinux wiki here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/arch_compared_to_other_distributions), Arch Linux is a **full rolling release** OS which is basically "true rolling release OS":

> Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) is based on Debian Stable and only
>   receives updates in Mint packages and security updates. Arch is
>   instead a full rolling-release distribution.

I understand that to be the highest one can go in rolling upgrades and of release as well.